# symfony2 login remember me

Tags: symfony

I am trying to implement functionality in Symfony2 Remember Me login.

I have this configuration file `security.yml`

```
security:

    firewalls:
        frontend:
            pattern:  ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
                default_target_path: /index
                success_handler: authentication_handler
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /login
                success_handler: authentication_handler
            security: true
            remember_me:
                key:      "%secret%"
                lifetime: 120
                path:     /
            access_denied_handler: accessdenied_handler
          #primero deben de ir los usuarios anonimos si no se entra en loop redirect
    access_control:
        - { path: /login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/js, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_A }
        - { path: ^/nuevoinforme, roles: ROLE_M }
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }

    providers:
        user_db:
            entity: { class: mio\mioBundle\Entity\Empleado, property: username }
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_M: ROLE_U
        ROLE_A: ROLE_U

    encoders:
        mio\mioBundle\Entity\Empleado: { algorithm: sha1 }
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
```

When I login, the cookie is properly stored on the client. However, after 120 seconds, while trying to access another URL, it still considers the client as logged-in while I expect it to be logged out and therefore I expect the client to be redirected to `/login`.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you rephrase the last sentence and ask a question? Your sentence is quite hard to understand.

Comment: I hope you understand me now. thanks sorry for my english

Comment: What is lifetime of your session? I suspect it's longer than 120 seconds, therefore you are still logged in because of your session.

Answer (score 0):

You set the `remember_me lifetime` to `120` therefore the cookie expires within 2 minutes.

You should set the lifetime value greater than a day.

```
security:
    firewalls:
        frontend:
            remember_me:
                lifetime: 120 # this value should be greater than 120 seconds
```

I stripped out the rest of the parameters so you can see what I am talking about.

Comment: thanks for your answer. because more than one day? I've been looking cookies and I have two: I remember I created that expires in 2 minutes and another PHPSESSID.
then always take PHPSESSID

How to remove the PHPSESSID cookie?

Comment: You don't remove them, PHPSESSID is related to the user session while the REMEMBERME cookie is related to security (if the cookie expires, the user is logged out).

Comment: the problem is that the cookie expires but not redirected to login when 120 seconds have passed. thanks.

Comment: a question. Does the session time has to be less than remember me cookie? thanks

Comment: I would say the session time and the remember me time should be equally long. Also, did you try closing your browser and check if you were still logged in?