# When the session expires, how can I force the user logout?

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to force the user when the session has expired becomes a logout but I can not access the time of the session

```
namespace mio\mioBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class RequestListener{

    protected $router;
    protected $security;  

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router, SecurityContext $security)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        echo $event->getRequest()->getSession()->('timeout');
    }
}
```

---

hello here I leave the configuration file security.yml.

```
security:

    firewalls:
        frontend:
            pattern:  ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
                default_target_path: /index
                success_handler: authentication_handler
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /login
                success_handler: authentication_handler
            security: true
            remember_me:
                key:      loksea
                lifetime: 1800
                path:     /
            access_denied_handler: accessdenied_handler
          #primero deben de ir los usuarios anonimos si no se entra en loop redirect
    access_control:
        - { path: /login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/pruebita, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/js, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_A }
        - { path: ^/nuevoinforme, roles: ROLE_M }
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }

    providers:
        user_db:
            entity: { class: mio\mioBundle\Entity\Empleado, property: username }
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_M: ROLE_U
        ROLE_A: ROLE_U

    encoders:
        mio\mioBundle\Entity\Empleado: { algorithm: sha1 }
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
```

When the session ends asks me to login again, but not user logout. I have a listener to save the logout so:

```
 public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request){
        $empleado =  $this->security->getToken()->getUser();
        $log = new Log();
        $log->setFechalog(new \DateTime('now'));
        $log->setTipo("Salida");
        $log->setEmpleado($empleado);
        $this->em->persist($log);
        $this->em->flush();
}
```

Would you call this method when the session ends? thanks.

Comment: That's probably a [duplicated question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504525/symfony2-login-remember-me).

Comment: @ThomasPotaire I'd consider them different questions entirely, though it's possible they might share the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if I'm right, do you need to execute your method "onLogoutSuccess" when the user logs out ?
So the logout process works well, right ?

To logout explicitly, have you tried the "clear()" method of session object ?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, but I managed to create a listener that throws a CredentialsExpiredException when the user reached the maximum idle time.
Users that have been idle for too long will be redirected to the login/logout page (for your situation its "/login" by looking at your logout target).
This is how I resolved the problem.

```
namespace mio\mioBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CredentialsExpiredException;

class RequestListener{

    protected $container;  

    public function __construct(Container $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $session = $this->container->get('session');
        $maxTime = 5*60; //5 minutes is the maximum lifetime

        // Get the current idle time and compare it with the max allowed time
        if (time() - $session->getMetadataBag()->getLastUsed() > $maxTime) {
            //Invalidate the current session and throw an exception
            $session->invalidate();
            throw new CredentialsExpiredException();
        }
    }
}
```

This should be it. If you have some additional questions please let me know!

Comment: Oops I forgot to change the constructor to the correct code. Thanks for de heads-up.

Comment: Furhter optimization would be setting $session instead of $container in constructor.

Answer (score -2):

You need to configure this behaviour in your security.yml config file, and it should work automatically.

Voilà

Comment: You answer is really poor. Can you include the configuration for example?